# No marketplace entries found to handle Execution default-proguard

Tags: java, android, eclipse, maven

I'm trying to import a maven project (the Ignition library for Android, https://github.com/kaeppler/ignition) and it's giving me 6 "Execution default-proguard" errors on the "Setup maven plugin connectors" screen:

```
No marketplace entries found to handle android-maven-plugin:3.0.2:proguard 
in Eclipse.    Please see Help for more information.


No marketplace entries found to handle Execution default-proguard, in 
ignited-async-task-sample/pom.xml in Eclipse.  Please see Help for more 
information.


No marketplace entries found to handle Execution default-proguard, in ignited
http-sample/pom.xml in Eclipse.  Please see Help for more information.


No marketplace entries found to handle Execution default-proguard, in 
ignition-core-lib/pom.xml in Eclipse.  Please see Help for more information.


No marketplace entries found to handle Execution default-proguard, in 
ignition-location-lib/pom.xml in Eclipse.  Please see Help for more information.


No marketplace entries found to handle Execution default-proguard, in 
ignition-location-sample/pom.xml in Eclipse.  Please see Help for more information.


No marketplace entries found to handle Execution default-proguard, in
remote-image- view-sample/pom.xml in Eclipse.  Please see Help for more information.
```

Anyone know what's causing these?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known issue with the [m2e-android](http://rgladwell.github.com/m2e-android/) extension:

https://github.com/rgladwell/m2e-android/issues/60

A pre-release version is available from this update site:

http://rgladwell.github.com/m2e-android/updates/master/

Comment: @yourfriendzak no it isn't, that's a link for an Eclipse update site: http://agile.csc.ncsu.edu/SEMaterials/tutorials/install_plugin/index_v35.html

Comment: Yes! Works fine. Now I just need to get ignition-support to compile to a JAR, as it can't be used as an android library like the other ignition modules.

Comment: Cool API, do they not have a JAR in the Maven central repo?

Comment: Don't think so...you have to compile the ignition-support directory with maven, then a JAR will show up in the ignition/ignition-support/ignition-support-lib/target/ folder. https://groups.google.com/group/ignition-users/browse_thread/thread/8224d92fdb3dc421

Comment: Worked for me! At last... :-)