# How to Get Eclipse, Maven and Google PlayN to work together?

Tags: android, eclipse, maven, playn

I have tried three times now to get eclipse setup to run the playn-sample projects with no luck. I have tried the following starter guides:

http://davies-barnard.co.uk/2012/03/playn/

http://code.google.com/p/playn/wiki/GettingStarted

http://www.gamefromscratch.com/post/2011/10/13/Getting-started-with-PlayN.aspx

And have been able to get up to the import part of the guides when I start running into issues.  I have cleaned out all JRE, JDK Eclipses installs, and currently have the following installed.

Java SE SDK 6u29

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase6-419409.html#jdk-6u29-oth-JPR

Android SDK r18

http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers

http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/indigor

m2e - Maven Integration for Eclipse v1.0.200.20111228-1245

(from all available update sites)

Android Plugin for Eclipse ver. 18.0.0.v201203301601-306762

https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

Google Plugin

http://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/3.7

Maven Integration for WTP ver. 0.15.2.20120306-2040

http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/m2eclipse-wtp

My experience starts deviating from the guides when I try to import the the playn-samples into the workspace.  I keep getting the following error:

> No marketplace entries found to handle android-maven-plugin:3.1.1:proguard in Eclipse.  Please see Help for more information.

While I have been programming for years, my time has been in visual studio predominantly C#,ASP.NET, and in the past two years I have picked up jQuery/JavaScript.  I programmed some in java back in college and saw the PlayN framework as a good reason to get back in.  What am I missing from these guides to get up and running?

Comment: That's just it.  I have found no suggestions or solutions for the marketplace errors I get when attempting import.  I have already fixed the java errors that seem to be common.  But I have no experience with Android, Maven, or Eclipse.  hence why I am asking for a direction to try.

Comment: @j4y: The question is for something before the fellow can get on with his programming. And he has mentioned what he has already "tried".

Comment: For **No marketplace entries found** error, see if Ricardo's answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9070768/no-marketplace-entries-found-to-handle-execution-default-proguard) helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issues like you.

Since i gave up with eclipse, i tried with Netbeans, and now i'm programming and testing the library.

Quickly, this is what i did:

1. Get the Netbeans+Java SE combo from here:
   http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk-netbeans-jsp-142931.html
   and install it
2. Launch Netbeans, go **to File > New Project > Maven > Project from Archetype > Next**
3. In the next dialog, push the **Add** button
4. A new window will pop-up. Switch to your web browser
5. Go to http://search.maven.org/ and in the search box type **playN**
6. In the resulting list, look for **playn-archetype** in the **ArtifactID** column and click it
7. Remember that last window on Netbeans? Return to the IDE and start filling the Group Id, Artifact Id and Version fields as they appear on the result list of playn-archetype. For example, the Group Id is com.googlecode.playn, Artifact Id is playn-archetype and the
   latest Version is 1.2 at this moment
8. Leave the Repository field in blank and click **Ok**
9. Now select your recently added archetype from the list and click **Next**
10. On the following dialog, you can left the fields or change them of you want. **BUT**, in the *Additional Creation Properties* section, make sure that you enter a value in the
    **JavaGameClassName** field. This will be the name of your main class, so make sure to fill it or after clicking Finish it will mark an error and you'll have to start over again.
11. Click **Finish** and Netbeans will start downloading a bunch of stuff, so be patient and wait until it's done. Great! Now you have a working project of PlayN ready to run. Just look for *[your-project-name] Java* folder in the Project Navigator, right click on it and select **Run**
12. If a error related to android appears, you need to go to *[your-project-name] Metaproject > Project Files* and open the **pom.xml** file. Open it and in the *modules* section, comment or delete the `<module>android</module>` line, just for now to quiclky
    test your project.
13. Remember, the  Core folder is where you'll programm the game and the others are the launchers for each
    platform(Java, Android, iOS...)

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Good instructions, but now I am getting an error I wasnt expecting.  Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.2:generate (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: Archetype com.googlecode.playn:playn-archetype:1.2 is not configured
Property JavaGameClassName is missing. I setup the variable from the instructions for the JaveGameClassName.  Is this in regards to the libraries?